# converting mysql data to json url

Tags: php, mysql, json

i tried to solve this problem when i convert Mysql data to json using php i got white page when i use 
my database collison is `utf8_general_ci`

```
<?php
include("config.php");
header('Content-Type: text/html; 
charset=utf-8');
$result = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM student');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $stu[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($stu);
?>
```

what is the problem ? 
Note : database is full and when i replace `echo json_encode` with `print_r` it got 
like this

���:8��Amr+ aS��>潶���D�^�!���f�'{m<��*���القلب�j�E�K�b�/*��ZƢ�ĵc+���9��V"x�,���2չV�9'�

Comment: Try using `json_encode( $stu, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );` Reference [here](http://se2.php.net/json_encode)

Comment: or change your  collision to `utf_8_bin` and then try to save data and fetch data

Comment: still not working

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos i tried ur code but still view white page

Comment: if database has image is that made problem ? my database has image and text

Comment: First try to `print_r($stu);` to be sure that it holds data. If it holds then something is wrong with the headers/encoding. Reply when you check that `$stu` variable holds the data that you want.

Comment: the wrong was in storing image in blob datatype i changed it to text and put the path of the image

Answer (score 0):

You need change the header to :
header('Content-Type: application/json');

```
    <?php
    include("config.php");
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $result = mysqli_query($db, 'SELECT * FROM student');
    $stu = array(); 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($stu,$row);
    }
    echo json_encode($stu);
    ?>
```

Comment: I changed the way that the array was working. Try this way and see if works.

Comment: if database has image is that made problem ? my database has image and text